# How to handle a failed job laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing multiple calls to different api's on my cron job, like:

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    $job = (new SendApplicationToBank($transaction));
    $this->dispatch($job);
}
```

One transaction has many banks so I am sending a transaction to all banks related:

Job:

```
public function handle(){
    try {
        $result = app($bankClass)::sendLoanApplication($this->transaction);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Silent fail
    }
}
```

The problem is that its failing on the first bank and just keeps retrying.

How should go and cofigure so If a job fails just release back to queue and continue the next one ?

Results:

[php artisan queue:listen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBhvB.png)

Answer (score 8):

You should not catch the `Exception` to let the job fail properly. Now you are catching it and doing nothing (`//Silent fail`)

You should make a table in your database to catch the failed jobs automatically with:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
```

In the script running your queue you should add the number of tries before failing:

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

It's also smart to add some kind of timeout:

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=60
```

And you can also call a webhook on fail by adding a failed method to you job:

```
public function failed()
{
    // Called when the job is failing...
}
```

Comment: yeah its clear in the picture above that I am using tries in this case. Also I am using redis not mysql

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it was a picture link. Maybe it's better you copy the output and add it to your question as code.

Comment: I think you should not catch the exception to let the job fail. Now you are catching the exception but not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

Running a command with limited tries you can run the following command

```
php artisan queue:work --retry=3
```

it will try to run your job only three-time

and programmatically you can use

```
    public $tries = 3;
```

in your job class

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah its clear in the picture above that I am using tries in this case.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch the exception the job does not silently fail but it is actually considered successful. You should either explicitly fail the job in the catch clause with `$this->fail()` or throw an exception. Throwing an exception will retry the job though, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

use `$this->release()` to release the job back to queue.